# wrapfigure and figure framed in text

Tags: wrapfigure

I'm trying to put an image framed by a text using this script.

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{infit.jpeg} 
  \caption{Infit per item}
  \label{fig:esempio}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

the text doesn't picture the photo, the caption is on the side of it and {l}{0.3 appears on the other side. how can i solve?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In this way we can copy-paste the code and look at the problem without resorting to wild guesses about what you are doing. Right now you are basically confiding in our clairvoyance...

Comment: \documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{infit.jpeg} 
  \caption{Infit per item}
  \label{fig:esempio}
\end{wrapfigure}

Dalla rappresentazione grafica si può notare una differenza dall'ordine di severità degli item proposta nella \textit{Figure 3}: le curve logistiche posizionate più verso destra sull'asse delle x, che rappresenta il livello di tratto latente d
\end{document}

Comment: Please don't post code as comment but rather edit your question. And again please a *complete*  code, if you really have `\documentclass{article} \begin{wrapfigure}` in your code then you're clearly doomed...

Comment: @Andrea Please add your code to the question (so we can read it with line breaks etc.) and also show which packages you load.

Answer (score 1):

To long for the comment ...

If I insert your code fragment to article,  which is prepared to accept wrap figures, and use example image available in any LaTeX document, I got expected result. So, source of your problem probably is in preamble of your document, which is unknown to us.

An example of a small but complete and working document with your code fragment, which preamble you can compare with yours in your document, is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text filler

\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption} 
\usepackage{graphicx}   % for inserting of image
 
\usepackage{wrapfig}    % essential


\begin{document} 
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}%{infit.jpeg} 
    \caption{Infit per item}
    \label{fig:esempio}
\end{wrapfigure} 
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Compilation of above MWE (Minimal Working Example) gives:

[image]

For finding source of your problem yourself, please make comparison between above MWE and your document and see, if your document's preamble contains packages present in mine MWE.

For (better) help you you should provide MWE, which reproduce your problem!